# mysql data inline command

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use "load data local infile" in mysql and set a column to a certain value...

So for example if my commannd is:

```
mysql_query('load data local infile "'.$filename.'" into table products fields terminated by "|" lines terminated by "\n" (column2, column3, column4)');
```

Then have a table like this

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4
```

can set column 1 equal to value I choose and have it done in this query? I am trying to have column 1 be equal to the filename it is importing...how would I set this into the sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [load data infile syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) you can do it like this:

```
mysql_query('load data local infile "'.$filename.'" into table products fields terminated by "|" lines terminated by "\n" (column2, column3, column4) SET column1=\'' . $filename . '\'');
```

From the link above: "The SET clause can be used to supply values not derived from the input file..."

(I'm not sure if something is messed up with single/double quotes...didn't try it).